# How to execute an oracle query in UNIX with help of shell script?

Tags: unix

How to execute an oracle query in UNIX with help of shell script?

I have tried with below script but it is not working,please help me on this

My requirement is:
i have two date values in CNTL_INF_OP.txt file which is located on server, like one value in line 1 and 2nd value in line 2 as shown below:

```
06-May-16 12:02:47 AM
11-May-16 12:30:15 AM
```

i need to use those two date values in the where clause of the below query and i need to execute that query and i need to export the output of that query into a flat file.

To get the above mentioned output, i tried with below script but it is not working, can anybody help me on this...i am new to UNIX..

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
START_TIME=`echo sed -n '1p'CNTL_INF_OP.txt`;
echo $START_TIME
END_TIME=`echo sed -n '2p'CNTL_INF_OP.txt`;
echo $END_TIME

sqlplus -S << EOF > /nbcdevwc01/appl_data/CDW2/sql/test_SQL_OP.txt
USERID/PASSWORD@DBNAME
set linesize 1000
set head off
set echo on

select min(SCN) , max(SCN) ,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MIN(SCN)) , SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(SCN)) 
FROM SYS.SMON_SCN_TIME WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(SCN) BTEWEEN $START_TIME AND $END_TIME;
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: I'd advise you to put some `echo` commands in the script, in order to know what's going on. In top of that, try to open a SQLPLUS connection, using the mentioned username and password (maybe that's the problem), and try to manually launch the SQL query. By the way, what do you mean by "it is not working"? Do you have an error message, if yes which one, or are the results you get not in line with what you expect?

Comment: if i run this script, one output file is generating, but it is not opening, it seems the script which i created is wrong, so provide me the correct script for my requirement.